# POST JSON data with cURL

Tags: javascript, json, curl

I want to POST some JSON data to a server. I have constructed one javascript object for that:

```
var formData;
formData[0] = {
value : accx.toString();
}
```

Now the post function is:

```
function postdata(){
        var accx = acc.x;

        }
```

`acc.x` is generated in a function and I will call `postdata()` function from that function. The cURL data POST example I got is:

```
curl -i -X PUT https://abcd.com/v1/feeds/5e5530142d3wecwecwec28265eabe/streams/acc_x -H "X-API-KEY: 2b9e2596eafwefwef6a7956e6f7a" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{ "value": "40" }'
```

Now what I want is I want send data like `-d '{ "acc_x": "0.2319393291" }'` continuously [generated data, not same value]
But I am not getting how to that. Anyone please help :)

Another problem is, the // in url will be seen as comment. so how to address this? Please suggest and help.

Answer (score 0):

Do you get an error back? I suggest you change your -i to -v, in order to get a verbose response to give you more information.

Also your curl command uses PUT and not POST as you say; please clarify if the question is about one or the other?

Finally, try to remove the quote marks from you numeric values, you don't need them.

Comment: i got nothing. Mistakenly written PUT . It will be POST. I want to POST say: var `accx = 1234` , then fromData object will construct that JSON ie. `{ "value" : "1234" }` Now I want to post data via cURL. Here it is passing hard coded data. My aim is to construct js object and create json, then passing dynamic data. Can you please suggest me out what thing should I change?

Comment: Yes. This link is absolute correct if I execute that command from command line. ie. `curl -i -X PUT "https://abcd.com/v1/feeds/5e5530142d3qwsqweqws323828265eabe/streams/acc_x" -H "X-M2X-KEY: 2b9e25964wwsqb16a7956e6f7a" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{ "value": "100" }'`

Comment: and I checked and got that POST not supported hence I did PUT and it is working from terminal (ubuntu) but not sure how to make it work from Javascript that too creating javascript object to form JSON